# convert/map python dictionary to a list, by using the key as the list index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a python dictionary as follows:

```
dict = {4:0.65,8:1.23,3:0.43}
```

I would like to convert this to a python list by using the key as the index to the list.  The desired converted result would be:

```
listLength = 10
plist = [0,0,0,0.43,0.65,0,0,0,1.23,0]
```

I know how to do the above using a loop but that is not pythonic and it is not fast.  What is the most pythonic way to do the above without using a loop.

I specially need to do the above with the best performance.

Comment: How to do you get the length of the list?

Comment: Good point. I'll update the question.  That's already known.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tag `pandas`, solution from `reindex`

```
pd.Series(d).reindex(range(10),fill_value=0).tolist()
Out[369]: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.43, 0.65, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.23, 0.0]
```

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy` and `numpy` indexing is going to be the most performant solution:

```
out = np.zeros(10)
out[list(d.keys())] = list(d.values())
```

```
array([0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.43, 0.65, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.23, 0.  ])
```

***Performance*** since you asked:

```
k = np.random.randint(1, 100000, 10000)
v = np.random.rand(10000)
d = dict(zip(k, v))

In [119]: %%timeit
     ...: out = np.zeros(100000)
     ...: out[list(d.keys())] = list(d.values())
     ...:
     ...:
1.86 ms ± 13.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [120]: %timeit [d.get(i, 0) for i in range(100000)]
17.4 ms ± 231 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [121]: %timeit pd.Series(d).reindex(range(100000),fill_value=0).tolist()
9.77 ms ± 148 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: 5 times faster than using a panda series.  sounds like the winner as I really need the performance.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For larger data sets you can gain some speed using `np.fromiter` directly on the key and value iterators instead of creating lists first.

Create test case

```
>>> d = dict(zip(np.random.randint(1, 10, 1_000_000).cumsum(), np.arange(1_000_000.)))
>>> out = np.zeros(10_000_000)
```

Define `fromiter` method

```
>>> def use_iter():
...     k, v = (np.fromiter(w, dtype=t, count=len(d)) for w, t in [(d.keys(), int), (d.values(), float)])
...     out[k] = v
...     return out
```

and `list` method for reference

```
>>> def use_list():
...     out[list(d.keys())] = list(d.values())
...     return out
```

and time them

```
>>> timeit(use_iter, number=100)
4.2583943260106025
>>> timeit(use_list, number=100)
17.10310926999955
```

Also, check correctness

```
>>> np.all(use_list() == use_iter())
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to something like this:

```
list_length = 10
d = {4: 0.65, 8: 1.23, 3: 0.43}
plist = [d.get(i, 0) for i in range(list_length)]

print(plist)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0.43, 0.65, 0, 0, 0, 1.23, 0]
```

**Note:** Don't use the name dict for your own variables, you will shadow the built-in name `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid shadowing the built-in `dict`. Use some other name instead.

```
dict_ = {4:0.65,8:1.23,3:0.43}
length = max(dict_) + 1  # Get number of entries needed
list_ = [0] * length  # Initialize a list of zeroes
for i in dict_:
    list_[i] = dict_[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

```
lst = [d[i] if i in d else 0 for i in range(10)]
print(lst)
# [0, 0, 0, 0.43, 0.65, 0, 0, 0, 1.23, 0]
```

Expanded:

```
lst = []
for i in range(10):
    if i in d:
        lst.append(d[i])
    else:
        lst.append(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the dictionary and place them into a list. I am doing error checking to make sure that the key is within the specified list length.

```
  list = [0] * length
    for key, val in d.items():
        if key < length:
            list[key] = val
```

If you want the list to be as big as the max key, follow this bellow

```
maxKey = max(d, key=int)
list = [0] * maxKey
for key, val in d.items():
    list[key] = val
```